# Can python 'import' be extended to other archive types than zip?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The `zipimport` module is automatically used by the standard import to handle `.zip` sys.path elements.

Is it possible to add hooks to support other file types? for example a handler for `.tar.gz`?

so for example, if sys.path contains `/path/to/archive.tar.gz` or `/path/to/archive.xyz` handlers can be provided to open and read `.tar.gz` or `.xyz` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways of doing this:

1. Overwrite the [`__builtin__.__import__()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#__import__) function with your own custom implementation.  This is a low-level way of completely overriding what the `import` keyword does, and is not recommended for general use.
2. Add a [finder](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-finder) object to [`sys.meta_path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.meta_path) which implements the desired functionality, or add a callable which returns such a finder to [`sys.path_hooks`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.path_hooks).  Finders are easier to implement in Python 3 than in Python 2, because 3.x provides a lot of building blocks in [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html).  However, they can be implemented in Python 2 as well (you just have to write more code).

In general, (2) is much easier than (1) regardless of 2.x vs 3.x.  (1) is only recommended as a last resort.  For more on (2), see [PEP 302](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/).